# What is the exception safety guarantee for getter (by value) methods?

Tags: c++, exception, exception-safety

For the following example class, what are the [exception safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) guarantees for the getter methods?

Do such getter methods offer a minimum of a strong guarantee?

Does returning a fundamental type by value always offer a no throw guarantee?

```
class Foo
{
public:

    // TODO: Constructor

    // Getter methods
    int getA() const { return a; }
    std::string getB() const { return b; }
    std::vector<int> getC() const { return c; }
    Bar getD() const { return d; }
    std::vector<Bar> getE() const { return e; }

protected:
    int a;
    std::string b;
    std::vector<int> c;
    Bar d;
    std::vector<Bar> e;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that all of your operations satisfy Strong exception safety, provided (where relevant) that the `Bar(const Bar&)` copy constructor is strongly safe.  Additionally, `getA` will satisfy the nothrow guarantee, provided that `a` is initialised, e.g. in the constructor.

No part of `Foo` is modified by these `const` methods, so the main concern is leakage of the newly-created `vector`s - these should be deallocated automatically if there's an exception in copying the members from `c` or `e` to the return value.

The reason that `a` must be initialised properly is that copying uninitialised data may throw on architectures such as Itanium, as described in [Bathsheba's answer](/a/32759123/4850040).

Answer (score 3):

There are no guarantees of exception safety at all.

For example, `getA()` might throw an exception if `a` is not initialised (or do anything else for that matter since the behaviour would be undefined). Some chips (e.g. Itanium) do signal if an unitialised variable is read.

`getC()` could throw `std::bad_alloc` if you're low on memory. Ditto `getB()`, `getD()` and `getE()`.

Comment: Even if getB would be no except it could throw bad_alloc. Fyi

Comment: I understand what you are saying about for `getA()` - to never throw I need to make sure constructors (inc. copy and move) always initialise `a`.  However, if any getter throws an exception won't this be classed as a strong guarantee because the state of the class has not been modified?